# How to enable Emmet's tab key handler (HTML shortcuts) within JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, sublimetext, reactjs, emmet

By default the tab key handler only works within JavaScript strings. I'd like to use it within JSX files which have a .JS file extension (and the tags do not occur within strings.)

Comment: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#tab-key-handler

Comment: 'Copied replace string from buffer' is displayed in the console when I press Ctrl + E (Sublime Text 3 build 3083). Thank you Sergey

Answer (score 0):

Most of the following was taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/max-mykhailenko/41d0c3991d92f38dcbc6)

### Preliminary Steps

1. Install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation)

Using Package Control...

2. Install [Emmet for Sublime Text 3](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet)
3. Install [Reg Replace](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RegReplace)
4. Install [Chain of Command](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command)

#### With  those installed...

Open `Preferences > Key Bindings - User` and add the following mapping:

```
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "chain", 
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        ["expand_abbreviation_by_tab"],
        ["reg_replace", {"replacements": ["js_class"]}]
      ]
    },
    "context": [
      {"operand": "source.js", "operator": "equal", "match_all": true, "key": "selector"}, 
      {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "(\\w+>\\w+|\\s(\\.?|a|div|span|p|button)\\.\\w+)", "match_all": true},
      {"key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true}
    ]

}
```

Open `Preferences > Package Settings > Reg Replace > Settings - User` and add the following. This will replace `class` with `className` as required in JSX syntax.

```
{
    "replacements": {
        "js_class": {
            "find": " class=\"",
            "replace": " className=\"",
            "greedy": true,
            "case": false
        }
    }
}
```